# Drawing radius for minimal_circle and diagonal for oriented_bbox in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator

Based on the expressions:

```
minimal_circle(collect($geometry))
```

[image]

```
oriented_bbox(collect($geometry))
```

[image]

I would like to use two expression that:

For the `minimal_circle` draw the radius and label its length:

[image]

For the `oriented_bbox` draw the diagonal and label its length

[image]

Comment: I think those are two separated question. The circle-thingy is rather straightforward, the bbox-thing a bit more complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed 2 separate questions.

To address the `minimum_circle`:

###### To draw the line

Create a LineString type Geometry Generator symbol layer with the following expression

```sql
with_variable('circle', minimal_circle(collect($geometry)),
    make_line(
        centroid(@circle),
        project(
            centroid(@circle),
            bounds_width(@circle) / 2,
            radians(45)   -- adjust to whatever angle you want the line to be drawn
        )
    )
)
```

###### To get the value for the label

The rounding can be removed, adjusted, or swapped for the `to_int` function. The string concatenation is also optional, it is just to include the measurement unit.

```sql
with_variable('circle', minimal_circle(collect($geometry)),
    round(bounds_width(@circle) / 2, 1) || ' m'
)
```

###### To get the placement for the label

Choose *Offset from point* and enable *Geometry Generator* placement

[image]

```sql
with_variable('circle', minimal_circle(collect($geometry)),
    project(
        centroid(@circle),
        bounds_width(@circle) / 2 + 100,
        radians(45)    -- adjust to the same angle as the first expression if you changed it
    )
)
```

`100` in this case is to offset the label from the edge of the circle. This can be adjusted to whatever is appropriate, of course (perhaps a factor of the circle's diameter).

###### Result

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For the box:

The diagonal symbol:

```
with_variable(name:='nodes', value:=
nodes_to_points( 
oriented_bbox(collect($geometry))
), expression:=
make_line( geometry_n( @nodes,1), geometry_n( @nodes,3)))
```

The label value:

```
round(length(
with_variable(name:='nodes', value:=
nodes_to_points( 
oriented_bbox(collect($geometry))
), expression:=
make_line( geometry_n( @nodes,1), geometry_n( @nodes,2)))),0)
```

The label placement:

```
point_n(
nodes_to_points( 
oriented_bbox(collect($geometry))
), 1)
```

[image]